# Calculating the sum of some records in SQL and entering them into a DataGridView

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to make a DataGridView that consists of 5 columns (Dish 1, Dish 2, Dish 3, Total Kcal, Total Price). For that, i have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Menu] (
    [id_product]       INT        NOT NULL,
    [product_name]  NCHAR (50)    NOT NULL,
    [description]       TEXT      NULL,
    [price]             INT       NOT NULL,
    [kcal]              INT       NOT NULL,
    [dish]              INT       NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id_product] ASC)
   );
```

I know how to select the same column 3 times, but not how to add the other 2 colums

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT (SELECT product_name FROM Menu WHERE dish = 1) AS Dish1, (SELECT product_name FROM Menu WHERE dish = 2) AS Dish2, (SELECT product_name FROM Menu WHERE dish = 3) AS Dish3", connexion);
        sda.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

EDIT: In the menu table i have these (i have only put the important fields)

```
+---------------+---------------+---------- +-----------+
| product_name  | price         | Kcal      | Dish      |
+---------------+---------------+---------- +-----------+
| Soup          | 20            | 120       |   1       |
| Chicken Soup  | 25            | 200       |   1       |
| Chocolate     | 30            | 250       |   3       |
| Ice Cream     | 35            | 500       |   3       |
| Chicken breast| 50            | 210       |   2       |
| Potatoes      | 40            | 340       |    2      |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

And, for example, the first row in the dataGridView should look like this:

```
Dish1                Dish2                Dish3       Total_Kcal    Total_Price

Soup                Chicken Breast       Ice Cream         830           105
Chicken soup        Chicken Breast       Ice Cream         910           110
Soup                Potatoes             Chocolate         710            90

etc.
```

EDIT : The point is that this should generate every combination of the 3 dishes with the total kcals and total price for each 3 products.

Comment: You have two product_name per dish on what basis you have chosen the result to have one product_name per dish

Comment: @Prdp I have only written the first row to be displayed.

Comment: For example, consider `Dish 1`. On what basis you have chosen  `Soup` instead of `Chicken soup`. What is the criteria ?

Comment: @Prdp I edited it, i hope you understand now.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this

```sql
SELECT Max(CASE WHEN dish = 1 THEN product_name END),
       Max(CASE WHEN dish = 2 THEN product_name END),
       Max(CASE WHEN dish = 3 THEN product_name END),
       Sum(Kcal) as Total_Kcal,
       Sum(price) as Total_price
FROM   yourtable 
Where dish in (1,2,3) -- to sum the price & Kcal of dish 1,2 & 3 alone
```

Comment: It doesn't give me and error, but the data just won't show. Any help ?

Comment: @Liviu - can you add sample data of your table and expected result

Comment: @Liviu - Not in comment.. Add it in question please

Comment: @Liviu - add sample data in question.. Dont add it in comment

Answer (score 0):

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter
        ("SELECT
         (SELECT product_name = 
          CASE WHEN DISH =1 THEN Dish1  
               WHEN DISH =2 THEN Dish2  
               WHEN DISH =3 THEN Dish3  
          END 
          ,SUM (kcal) AS Total Kcal
          ,SUM (price) As Total Price

          FROM Menu
          GROUP BY KCAL, Price 
          HAVING DISH IN (1,2,3)
 -- OR YOU CAN USE IF THIS IS Different scenario then
-- HAVING KCAL <= 3 AND PRICE <=3            
        ",connexion)
```

Comment: What if i need to add another column for choosing the record ? (And the Total Kcal and Total price should only be for those 3 dishes.)

Comment: I have updated the above answer as per your request.

Comment: You need to use group by for KCAL and PRICe you already used SUM which is an aggregate Function you can use Group By  clause which is having this number of columns i.e 1 , 2 , 3,

Comment: I don't have  Dish1 or Dish2 or Dish3 as a field, in the post it was just an alias, and group by kcal, price doesn't make it to calculate the sum of kcal and price of those 3 records. What i was saying is that the total kcal should be the total kcal of dish 1, dish 2, dish 3 in each row